# Using Javascript to click a specific link , named 'next', using CSS selectors

Tags: javascript

## Intro

I want to write JavaScript to click on `Next` at the bottom right:

[image]

Alas  I can't link to the page because it requires you to login,  but it's [similar to this page](https://concept.droppages.com/)

## CSS Selectors

this link that I want to click is always at :

```
.a-last > a
```

The CSS selector for this is `.a-last > a`

I got this information using a browser plug called "Click to remove element".

## Class Name

Other ideas for selecting this link:

- It's the second web element on the page with class `larr`

## Final link on page

I wonder if I can use `a:last` as it always happens to be this link . (this is not an ideal method, but it gets the job done)

## My attempt

### Using Class Names

I think i'll use class names

```
var pushNext = document.getElementsByClassName("larr")[1];
pushNext.click()
```

### Using CSS selectors

```
var pushNext = document.querySelector(".larr")[1];
pushNext.click()
```

or maybe i should use

```
var pushNext = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // so this picks all the links

// I need the next step to pick the last link

pushNext.click()
```

Am i on the right lines? I'm very much a novice.

Comment: You posted a similar question earlier, but it's unclear what your goal is here. What are you actually trying to do? We can't tell if the JS will work or what will work best because you haven't included any html.

Comment: The "right" answer will depend a bit on what other content might appear on this page... e.g. any other elements with the same classes etc.

Comment: You have a screenshot, some CSS and some JS.  You have not posted any HTML.  Please post a complete working code sample. Screenshots aren't really helpful for this, but all the code would be since this is a code question

Comment: Is there any good reason for not just directly calling the function that that button triggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the HTML from the page you linked to, a CSS selector like `document.querySelector('.a-pagination li:last-child a` might work better here.  You really want the last `<li>` item (I think you do anyway) and then you can just find the `<a>` inside of that.

```js
document.querySelector('.a-pagination li:last-child a').style.border="1px solid red"
```

```html
<ul class="a-pagination">
  <li class="a-disabled">←<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>Previous</li>
  <li class="a-selected"><a href="#" aria-current="page">1</a></li>
  <li class="a-normal"><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li class="a-normal"><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li class="a-normal"><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li class="a-normal"><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li class="a-last"><a href="#">Next<span class="a-letter-space"></span><span class="a-letter-space"></span>→</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is beautiful and exactly what I was looking for. I love the red border thing you did - it's excellent for demo/testing purposes